# Why ~N is doing -(N + 1) in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

Look at the below examples please:

```
console.log(~-2); //1
console.log(~-1); //0
console.log(~0); //-1
console.log(~1); //-2
console.log(~2); //-3
console.log(~true); //-2
console.log(~false); //-1
```

Why `~N` is operating like `-(N + 1)` ?

Comment: Didn't you just ask a question like this?

Comment: It's bitwise negation, or the *complement*. Add one and you get the *two's complement*, which is the most popular representation of -N.

Comment: It was different. This is another issue. Actually I thought this question should be asked to know tilda ~ really works and why the result is like -(N+1).

Comment: "Two's complement" math

Comment: Of course I know. It wasn't clear but after guys answers it is became more clear now!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It reverts all bits in number, and bit representation of integer number is as follows (for 3 bits numbers):

```
-4 = 100b
-3 = 101b
-2 = 110b
-1 = 111b
 0 = 000b
 1 = 001b
 2 = 010b
 3 = 011b
```

It works respectively for bigger numbers.

So by taking `~-2` you have `~(110b)`, which is equal to `001b` and that is `1`.

Comment: Changes 0 to 1, and 1 to 0

Comment: This, as my answer explains, is because of two's complement representation of integers. It would be the integer negation if using one's complement, for instance.

Answer (score 4):

The ~ operator is the [bitwise NOT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation#NOT) operator. ~ takes the operand bit by bit and changes zeroes by ones and ones by zeroes.

```
~ (00010110)b = (11101001)b
```

Now, the negative integers are represented using [Two's complement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement), which is exactly defined as executing bitwise NOT and adding one: then bitwise NOT is the same as negating the operand and substracting one:

```
 4 = (00000100)b
-4 = (11111100)b
-5 = (11111011)b = ~4
```

And you have the answer!

Answer (score 2):

Because bitwise not works on the binary representation of the values. Take -5 for example, which is represented as:

```
1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1011
```

in binary (32 bits)

Notting that value (flipping each bit from `1` to `0` or vice-versa) gives you:

```
0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0100
```

Which is 4 in decimal.

Answer (score 1):

When you convert to binary, it's easier to see what's happening:

```
 -1 → 11111111 11111111
~-1 → 00000000 00000000 →  0

  1 → 00000000 00000001
 ~1 → 11111111 11111110 → -2
```

Answer (score 1):

~ is a binary not. It inverts a number's bits. All numbers in JavaScript are signed, so the first bit is always a sign bit. Therefore positive numbers become negative and vice versa. -1 because -1 is the inverse of zero. See also [Bitwise operators at Mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript%2FReference%2FOperators%2FBitwise_Operators)

Answer (score 1):

In JavaScript, `~` is the bitwise "flip" operator. That means it will invert the bit values of the binary representation of a value. It only accepts integer values, so it will coerce any value that you pass to an int.

An integer in JavaScript[1] is signed, and represented using the [two's complement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signed_number_representations#Two.27s_complement) system. For instance (using 8 bits for simplicity):

```
2: 0000 0010
```

If we flip its bits we get

```
~2: 1111 1101
```

which is the binary representation (in two's complement) of `-3`, that's `-(2+1)`, as you pointed out.

[1] which is actually represented as floating point number, but that just makes it more confusing, and can be disregarded for practical purposes.